# how in webBrowser windows forms to do zoom to fit?

Tags: c#, youtube, webbrowser-control

Have a webBrowser component in windows forms c#, want to embed youtube video, but it zoom out and not show as expected..

In screenshot 1 and 2 images are from form, where i zoom in/out window youtube player is change his size as well, but 3 image are from chrome, it's what i want to do. How to do this?

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/Br8ii.png]

Comment: simple man 1 and 2 are in windows mode and here 3 is in the part of Browser here they used complete jquerry..

Comment: @Madhu yes, but how in webBrowser component to use jquery ?
simple want to show like in chrome, in a windows forms app. thanks.